# Confirmation dialog for deleting a comment does not appear twice

Tags: support, deleted-comments, confirmation

I don't consider this being very important, but I thought I'd report it (and perhaps it's by design).

I was cleaning up some of my old comments, and tried to delete one before 5 seconds had passed from the previous deletion, I got the "you cannot submit a comment for 5 seconds (click to dismiss)" alert.

I clicked, I waited 5 seconds, and when I clicked to delete it again, it got deleted without asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, I think, is actually a feature.

I tested it out on my Formatting Sandbox answer: the confirmation dialog is not shown if you try to delete the *same* comment you tried to delete before the warning was shown. If you try to delete any other comment, you get the confirmation box again.

I guess the theory is that if you're adamant about deleting that comment, you're not going to be happy about seeing the confirmation box again (and if you're impatient, *again*).