# Deleting your own comments too quickly produces the "hey you're voting too fast!" error

Tags: bug, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Possible bug: are comment deletion and comment votes supposed to use the same backend?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47412/possible-bug-are-comment-deletion-and-comment-votes-supposed-to-use-the-same-bac)
>   [Confirmation dialog for deleting a comment does not appear twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47293/confirmation-dialog-for-deleting-a-comment-does-not-appear-twice)

I was deleting a series of comments I made (that had since become irrelevant). By clicking the little x's too quickly I got the message about how you can only vote for comments every five seconds. It seems like this restriction shouldn't apply, or at least the error could stand to be more accurate.

Comment: Dupe of [a question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47412/possible-bug-are-comment-deletion-and-comment-votes-supposed-to-use-the-same-bac) which was itself closed as a dupe of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47293/confirmation-dialog-for-deleting-a-comment-does-not-appear-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Visualize it so: you're basically voting for a delete. However, you're the owner so the vote immediately counts.

I however agree that the warning is unintuitive. It has also bothered me at times when I'm doing quick subsequent comment edits.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the reason, but obscure implementation details don't justify broken or hostile features.